# fill an array with non repeat key values php

Tags: php, arrays

I´m facing this issue, probably this is dumb... but here we go:

I have a regular foreach:

```
 foreach $values as $values => $key {
   $test[] = $key;
 }
```

of course test is defined outside the loop.

Now, this returns something like this:

```
 array(6) {
 [0]=> int(10)
 [1]=> int(16)
 [2]=> int(10)
 [3]=> int(16)
 [4]=> int(10)
 [5]=> int(16)
 [6]=> int(10)
 }
```

However, I need the repeated values to be ignored so test would be like this:

```
 array(2) {
 [0]=> int(10)
 [1]=> int(16)
 }
```

And new values are only added if and only if, it is not repeated. I already tried array_unique and array_values however I'm not use If I am implementing them bad or what is the issue...

Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want

Comment: What was wrong when using `array_unique`? Also see `in_array`.

Comment: it reuturns null for some reason

Comment: You're overriding `$values` in your loop, after the loop `$values` becomes the last element in the array, not the array itself.

Comment: Is it just me or is `foreach $values as $values => $key ` the worst possible var names ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to add the value if it doesn't exist, use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
 $test=array();
    // organize the array by cusip
    foreach ($values as $values => $key) { 
            if(!in_array($key, $test)){
            $test[]=$value;
            }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `array_unique()`?

Consider this an example:

```
$values = array_unique($values);
```

or if you do not want to use `array_unique()`, you can do it in another way:

```
foreach ($values as $index => $element) {
    if(!in_array($element, $values)) {
        $test[] = $element;
    } 
}
```

Comment: yeah but for some reason this returns null on the key values

Answer (score 1):

How about assigning the array using *array_unique*:

```
<?php
    $x = array
    (
        0 => 'int(10)',
        1 => 'int(16)',
        2 => 'int(10)',
        3 => 'int(16)',
        4 => 'int(10)',
        5 => 'int(16)',
        6 => 'int(10)'
    );

    $x = array_unique($x);
    print_r($x);
?>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => int(10)
    [1] => int(16)
)
```

Comment: now this worked, thanks a ton, it made the trick, i knew it was something silly, i was applying array_unique into the foreach to the $w.

Answer (score 1):

If `array_unique` somehow won't work for you, you could use:

```
<?php
foreach( $values as $values => $key ){
   if( !in_array($key, $test) )
      $test[] = $key;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your array is

```
$test = array(6) {
 [0]=> int(10)
 [1]=> int(16)
 [2]=> int(10)
 [3]=> int(16)
 [4]=> int(10)
 [5]=> int(16)
 [6]=> int(10)
 }
```

You can use `array_unique($test)` which will removes duplicate values.

Comment: Could you add some explanation and maybe an example? As it stands this answer is too short.